# Why doesn't my file load the ArrayList /w Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Well, I want to set up a login system for a multiplayer game and I've tried to write code for the server side login check. The username and password should be saved in a file so I can shutdown the server without loss of data. I know it’s not a safe way to do this, but I need a starting point to build my prototype. If I´m in Puglish range I would look for alternative.

Any Idea why this doesnt work?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

[System.Serializable]
public class Login : MonoBehaviour {

    public ArrayList PlayerNames;
    public ArrayList PlayerPass;
    public GameObject LoginName;
    public GameObject Password;
    public string Playname;
    public string Playerpass;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Load();
        PlayerNames = new ArrayList();
        PlayerPass = new ArrayList();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


    }

    public  void Save()
    {

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream username = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/username.gd");
        FileStream password = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/password.gd");
        bf.Serialize(username, PlayerNames);
        bf.Serialize(password, PlayerPass);
        username.Close();
        password.Close();
        Debug.Log("Saved");
        Debug.Log(PlayerNames);

    }

    public void Load()
    {

        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/username.gd") && File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/password.gd"))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Loaded");

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream username = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/username.gd", FileMode.Open);
            FileStream password = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/password.gd", FileMode.Open);
            PlayerNames = (ArrayList)bf.Deserialize(username);
            PlayerPass = (ArrayList)bf.Deserialize(password);
            username.Close();
            password.Close();

        }
    }

    int i;
    string Playerpasz;
    public void CheckRegister()
    {
        Playname = LoginName.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        Playerpass = Password.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        if (PlayerNames.Contains(Playname))
        {
            int indexItem = PlayerNames.IndexOf(Playname);
            string pass = PlayerPass.IndexOf(indexItem).ToString();

            foreach(var Passworz in PlayerPass)
            {
                if (i == indexItem) {

                    Playerpasz = Passworz.ToString();
                    Debug.Log(Playerpasz);
                    i = 0;
                }
                indexItem++;
            }
            Debug.Log("Username found: " + PlayerNames.IndexOf(Playname));
           // Debug.Log("Pass1:" + Playerpasz);
           // Debug.Log("Pass2:" + Playerpass);

            if (Playerpasz == Playerpass)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Pasword found");
                LoginSucess();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Falsches Passwort");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Register();

        }
    }

    public void Register() {
        Debug.Log("Reg");
        PlayerNames.Add(Playname);
        PlayerPass.Add(Playerpass);
        Save();
        LoginSucess();
    }
    void LoginSucess()
    {
        Debug.LogError("Eingeloggt");

    }
}
```

Comment: why not use just `List`?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Two `ArrayList` where you have a list of usernames and passwords are definietly not suitable for this, you should offload your authentication data in a class like `class AuthData { public string UserName {get;set;} public string Password {get;set;} }` then have a `List<AuthData>` and check against that.

Comment: Everyone else is making it very complicated.  ***You absolutely should not use ArrayList***

Comment: Joe, yeah. The last time I saw the ArrayList was 4 years ago written in a vb.net project in 2003...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it won't work because of you initialization load order.
Check it out:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Load();
    PlayerNames = new ArrayList();
    PlayerPass = new ArrayList();
}
```

First you are Loading the Names and Passwords from file, and after that, you simply overwrite the info with a new empty ArrayList. Remove this lines and test again:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Load();
}
```

Remember that the `Start` method is called at the first time that the `GameObject` goes active.

Another good thing to do is what Maximilian said, instead having two arrays for the same group of information, why just don't create a serializable class with the Name and Pass being fields?

Comment: Well thanks, that was the problem... I feel so stupid, cause its not the first time that this happened to me xD

Comment: hi @StonedLover can click "delete" on this question to try to reduce clutter on the site